# Why tensorflow dataset neet to be batched before fit?

Tags: tensorflow

If we've made tensorflow dataset (for example from from_tensor_slices) we need to use .batch(...) method before we set this dataset as parameter of function fit(). Question is why method "fit" expect dataset to be batched ?

Comment: A [tag:tensorflow] batch is not a Windows, DOS, or OS/2 [tag:batch-file]. I have therefore removed your invalid tag, and ask in future that you read the information for each tag you use before assigning them to your questions.

Comment: that's just what it needs. what kind of answer are you expecting?

Comment: "that's just what it needs" -- this kind of answer can explain everything and also nothing. Error from "fit" method does not directly indicate the cause of the error, and in documentation is also omitted, so I ask

Comment: the developers decided that the first dimension of the tensor that enters the model must be the number of samples. when a dataset isn't batched, this isn't the case

Answer (score 1):

Datasets are sliced or batched for following reasons.

1. To avoid high memory usage if entire Dataset is used as one batch ( which might create Out of Memory problems)
2. Computation is faster when Training is done in Batches
3. Weight and Bias update is possible with respect to labels when training is done is batches.

Reference:
https://medium.com/@elimu.michael9/understanding-epochs-and-batches-23120a04b3cb